# Windows 10 completely switch system language

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

Running `Windows 10 Pro for Workstations` build `19042.867` I am having issues changing the system language from German which it shipped with to English (US).

#### What I did so far

Under `Time & Language` in the Windows settings I installed the english language pack, set it as the selected language, uninstalled the German language pack

[image]

and under "Administrative language settings" I copied it to all other users (I am the only user on this system). I also kept the German keyboard layout.

[image]

I also set the region settings to English (US) and rebooted.

[image]

#### The problem

Upon logging back in most of the system language has changed to English (as it should), HOWEVER when, for example, searching for `Network and Sharing Center` (which *should* yield results) it only gives back German search results:

[image]

As far as Google results go I already did everything described in these.

#### Other weird things I noticed

When I was later dealing with file permissions I found that the `nt-authority\system` user was still called `nt-autorität\system` as usual on German system. Upon escalating to the system user using `psexec -s -i cmd` and then running `intl.cpl` to view the language and regional settings of the system user it gave me the following screen.

[image]

#### The question

So eventhough I uninstalled the German language pack it seems there are still traces left of it on my system. Personally I don't really care about what language the `SYSTEM` user account uses and I don't know if it is related but I'd like to see my windows settings search results in English, not in German. Furthermore I'd like to rid myself of any traces that the System initially was installed using the German language pack (which I was unable to switch to English (United States) in the Windows Installer). So the following question arises:

**How do I *completely and system-wide* change the language to English (United States)?**

Comment: In another post where I answered, the only solution was to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), using the English Windows version.

Comment: Not fiddled around with these settings for a very long time, but you might want to check what language the local admin account uses - if that's still in German it will change the login screen language for example iirc.

Comment: Have a look at the PowerShell cmdlets `Get-WinSystemLocale` & `Set-WinSystemLocale`. `Get-WinUserLanguageList` may also be of use, with `Set-WinUserLanguageList` to refine the list of languages.

Comment: @MiG Interesting enough after enabling the build in admin account and switching to it the settings were all set to English for the admin account. So maybe one has to recreate the user account to apply the language? Even more interesting is that Windows Search is now working too for the admin user which was broken on my local user too. I'll do some more testing

Comment: The built-in Administrator account always exists it’s either disabled (cannot be accessed) or is enabled (can be accessed). If the problem exists with your own account then that’s the profile that should be recreated.  The built-in Administrator account CANNOT be deleted. I would change the input language and provide us the output of those commands